# Debian suddenly throws 'libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory' in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian, apt, debian-buster

I've been using the following Docker image (condensed for brevity) for a long time:

```
FROM elixir:1.11

ARG USER
ARG GROUP
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
ARG POSTGRESQL_VERSION=13
ARG POSTGRESQL_CLUSTER=my-cluster
ARG POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
ARG POSTGRESQL_DIR=/etc/postgresql/$POSTGRESQL_VERSION/$POSTGRESQL_CLUSTER
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN set -xe \
    && ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Portugal /etc/localtime \
    && groupadd -g $GID $GROUP \
    && useradd -r -u $UID -g $GROUP -m -s /bin/bash -c "Docker image user" $USER \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y lsb-release cmake \
    && echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian `lsb_release -cs`-backports bullseye main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing non-free contrib main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && wget -q -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-$POSTGRESQL_VERSION inotify-tools libgit2-dev vim expect nodejs lsof
```

However, I suddenly started experiencing the following error:

```
#6 31.36 Get:131 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.2.2434-3 [1494 kB]
#6 31.64 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#6 31.85 Fetched 175 MB in 6s (30.9 MB/s)
#6 31.87 Selecting previously unselected package gcc-11-base:amd64.
(Reading database ... 36509 files and directories currently installed.)
#6 31.90 Preparing to unpack .../gcc-11-base_11.2.0-4_amd64.deb ...
#6 31.90 Unpacking gcc-11-base:amd64 (11.2.0-4) ...
#6 31.95 Setting up gcc-11-base:amd64 (11.2.0-4) ...
#6 32.00 Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-s1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 36514 files and directories currently installed.)
#6 32.02 Preparing to unpack .../libgcc-s1_11.2.0-4_amd64.deb ...
#6 32.03 Unpacking libgcc-s1:amd64 (11.2.0-4) ...
#6 32.03 Replacing files in old package libgcc1:amd64 (1:8.3.0-6) ...
#6 32.08 Setting up libgcc-s1:amd64 (11.2.0-4) ...
(Reading database ... 36516 files and directories currently installed.)
#6 32.17 Preparing to unpack .../g++_4%3a10.2.1-1_amd64.deb ...
#6 32.18 Unpacking g++ (4:10.2.1-1) over (4:8.3.0-1) ...
#6 32.21 Preparing to unpack .../gcc_4%3a10.2.1-1_amd64.deb ...
#6 32.22 Unpacking gcc (4:10.2.1-1) over (4:8.3.0-1) ...
(Reading database ... 36516 files and directories currently installed.)
#6 32.32 Removing g++-8 (8.3.0-6) ...
#6 32.41 dpkg: gcc-8: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
#6 32.41  libtool depends on gcc | c-compiler; however:
#6 32.41   Package gcc is not configured yet.
#6 32.41   Package c-compiler is not installed.
#6 32.41   Package gcc-8 which provides c-compiler is to be removed.
#6 32.41   Package gcc which provides c-compiler is not configured yet.
#6 32.41
#6 32.41 Removing gcc-8 (8.3.0-6) ...
#6 32.44 dpkg: libgcc-8-dev:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
#6 32.44  libstdc++-8-dev:amd64 depends on libgcc-8-dev (= 8.3.0-6).
#6 32.44
#6 32.44 Removing libgcc-8-dev:amd64 (8.3.0-6) ...
(Reading database ... 36304 files and directories currently installed.)
#6 32.55 Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-17_amd64.deb ...
#6 32.66 Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
#6 32.67 Checking init scripts...
#6 32.69 Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.31-17) over (2.28-10) ...
#6 33.57 Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.31-17) ...
#6 33.60 /usr/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
#6 33.60 dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
#6 33.60  installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
#6 33.61 Errors were encountered while processing:
#6 33.61  libc6:amd64
#6 33.72 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After trying certain changes and going by trial and error I believe the culprit is the command

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing non-free contrib main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

I'm suspicious of this being related to the recent release of Debian Bullseye, but I'm not sure. I need the `testing` repository to fetch a `libgit2-dev` version from `1.0.0` onwards (the stable repository download `0.27.0`).

Some fixes I tried were installing `libssl-dev` and other crypto related packages but nothing seems to work so far. If I remove the command shown above it works, but installs the older version of `libgit2`.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any solution for this? I faced with similar issue 2 years later :)

Comment: I found this on a Debian thread, [Debian Bug 993755](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=993755)